# How to pass JSON in POST method with PhpUnit Testing?

Tags: json, phpunit, symfony, webtest

I am using symfony 3.0 with phpUnit framework 3.7.18

Unit Test file.
**abcControllerTest.php**

```
namespace AbcBundle\Tests\Controller;


use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class AbcControllerTest extends WebTestCase {


    public function testWithParams() {
        $Params = array("params" => array("page_no" => 5));
        $expectedData = $this->listData($Params);

        print_r($expectedData);
    }

    private function listData($Params) {
        $client = static::createClient();        
        $server = array('HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json', 'HTTP_ACCEPT' => 'application/json');
        $crawler = $client->request('POST', $GLOBALS['host'] . '/abc/list', $Params,array(), $server);
        $response = $client->getResponse();
        $this->assertSame('text/html; charset=UTF-8', $response->headers->get('Content-Type'));
        $expectedData = json_decode($response->getContent());
        return $expectedData;
    }

}
```

Action : abc/list

**abcController.php**

```
public function listAction(Request $request) {      
        $Params = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
}
```

Code is working fine but not given expected result.Since i am trying to pass json parameter from my phpunit file **abcControllerTest.php** to controller **abcController.php** file.
Anyone can suggest me how can i achieve the same things.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I prefer using `GuzzleHttp` for external requests :

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client();

$response = $client->post($url, [
    GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::JSON => ['title' => 'title', 'body' => 'body']
]);
```

Note: `GuzzleHttp` should be installed with e.g. using composer.

But you can always use client bundled with `Symfony`:

```
public function testJsonPostPageAction()
{
    $this->client = static::createClient();
    $this->client->request(
        'POST', 
        '/api/v1/pages.json',  
        array(),
        array(),
        array('CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'),
        '[{"title":"title1","body":"body1"},{"title":"title2","body":"body2"}]'
    );
    $this->assertJsonResponse($this->client->getResponse(), 201, false);
}

protected function assertJsonResponse($response, $statusCode = 200)
{
    $this->assertEquals(
        $statusCode, $response->getStatusCode(),
        $response->getContent()
    );
    $this->assertTrue(
        $response->headers->contains('Content-Type', 'application/json'),
        $response->headers
    );
}
```

Comment: `GuzzleHttp` is for making real HTTP request, while Symfony's client simulates a browser and makes requests to a `Kernel` object. The latter has a lot more APIs to simplify unit testing. It also removes the need to have a web server to run the unit test.

Answer (score 8):

A little late, but for Symfony 5, you have the `jsonRequest` accessible via any `WebTestCase`

```php
<?php
$this->client = static::createClient();

$this->client->jsonRequest('POST', '/myJsonEndpoint', [
    'key' => 'value'
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a bit late... but it can help someone.

with this you can build a generic POST request and will be accepted by your controller. it's on Symfony 4.x using framework's HTTP client

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$request = new Request([], [], [], [], [], ['HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'], {"foo":"bar"}));
```

Answer (score 1):

### CONTENT_TYPE vs HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE

**TLDR;**

For Symfony 5 use this:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$request = new Request(
    $uri, $method, $parameters, $cookies, $files,
    $server=['CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'], 
    $content={"foo":"bar"})
);
```

---

Careful, for Symfony **5.2**, **5.3** (maybe earlier too) code below not working:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$request = new Request(
    $uri, $method, $parameters, $cookies, $files,
    $server=['HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'], 
    $content={"foo":"bar"})
);
```

Why:

1. if no CONTENT_TYPE is set then it added to $server [there](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/e36c8e5502b4f3f0190c675f1c1f1248a64f04e5/Request.php#L393)
2. then it overrides HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE [there](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/e36c8e5502b4f3f0190c675f1c1f1248a64f04e5/ServerBag.php#L35)